# Need to get a concatenated SQL query working in Android App

Tags: android, sql, json

I have the following php working in my Android App

```
<?php

$myServer = "*****";
$myUser = "*****";
$myPass = "*****";
$myDB = "******"; 

//connection to the database
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>$myDB, "UID"=>$myUser, "PWD"=>$myPass);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionOptions);

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM JD Inner Join amipartnumbers on amipartnumbers.oemitem=JD.OEMCurrentPartNumber WHERE JD.OEMSubNumber = ?";
$params = array( $_REQUEST['search'] );

$data = sqlsrv_query( $conn ,$query, $params);  

$result = array();

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $result[] = $row;   
    }
}while ( sqlsrv_next_result($data) );

echo(json_encode($result));

sqlsrv_free_stmt($data);

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the code in the app that utilizes it

```
button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);

                try {
                    EditText txtSearch = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_oem);
                    String editTextStr = txtSearch.getText().toString();
                    url = "http://******/my.php?search=";
                    urlfinal = url+editTextStr;
                    String data = NetworkUtil.get(urlfinal);

                    if (data != null) {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
                        for (int x = 0; x < array.length(); x++) {
                            JSONObject node = array.getJSONObject(x);
                            String oemCurrent = node.getString("OEMCurrentPartNumber");
                            String oemSub = node.getString("OEMSubNumber");
                            String oemDescrip = node.getString("OEMDescription");
                            String amiNumber = node.getString("Item");
                            String amiDescrip = node.getString("Description");
                            oemcurrent.setText(oemCurrent);
                            oemdescription.setText(oemDescrip);
                            oemsub.setText(oemSub);
                            aminumber.setText(amiNumber);
                            amidescription.setText(amiDescrip);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Network ERROR!
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Parse ERROR!
                }
            }
        });
    }
public static class NetworkUtil {

        public static String get (final String url) throws IOException {
            InputStream in = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                in = httpEntity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        in, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return sb.toString();
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to add a new sql query that bring back a concatenated result.
I have this working on my aspx website as follows

```
Dim strSql = " SELECT * FROM JD Inner Join amipartnumbers on " &
            " amipartnumbers.oemitem=JD.OEMCurrentPartNumber WHERE " &
            " JD.OEMSubNumber = '" & enterNumber & "'" &
            " UNION SELECT * FROM IH Inner Join amipartnumbers on " & _
            " amipartnumbers.oemitem=IH.OEMCurrentPartNumber WHERE " & _
            " IH.OEMSubNumber= '" & enterNumber & "'"
        Dim strSql2 = "SELECT distinct OEMCurrentPartNumber,(SELECT OEMSubNumber+', ' FROM JD t2 WHERE t2.OEMCurrentPartNumber = t1.OEMCurrentPartNumber FOR XML PATH('')) Concatenated FROM JD t1 WHERE OEMSubNumber='" & enterNumber & "'"
        Dim strSql3 = "SELECT distinct OEMCurrentPartNumber,(SELECT OEMSubNumber+', ' FROM IH t2 WHERE t2.OEMCurrentPartNumber = t1.OEMCurrentPartNumber FOR XML PATH('')) Concatenated FROM IH t1 WHERE OEMSubNumber='" & enterNumber & "'"

Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString)
            Using cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = strSql
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                con.Open()
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 60
                Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If rdr.HasRows Then
                        retVal.Load(rdr)
                    End If
                End Using
                Me.txtSubs.Text = ""
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = strSql2
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 60
                Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While rdr.Read()
                        If rdr.Item(0).ToString <> "" Then
                            txtSubs.Text = (rdr.Item(1))
                        End If
                    End While
                End Using
                If Me.txtSubs.Text = "" Then
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandText = strSql3
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60
                    Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        While rdr.Read()
                            If rdr.Item(0).ToString <> "" Then
                                txtSubs.Text = (rdr.Item(1))
                            End If
                        End While
                    End Using
                End If
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
```

I have to sql queries that are concatenated because its searching two tables. if one results as empty it tries the other.

Like i said, that code it working fine on my website. I was wonder how i could utilize that in my Android app?

Comment: It seems you already have enough to do this. Could you add what you got up to and what specifically you are having problems with?

Comment: Well i have the original data working, but want to add the new sql that concatenates. i tried adding another php with that query and setting a new json to grab it but it keeps pulling data from the original query